# Was it Parvati who became Durga?

Tags: puranas, durga, kali, parvati

As far as I know Parvati and Kali are the same person .It was Parvati who became Kali.

Are Durga and Parvati also same person ? Was it Parvati who became Durga ? Are they the same woman ? Or Are they different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes They Are the Same Person. Durga is none other than Shiva's consort Parvati.

> 17-18. On getting their permission, he joyously entered the harem. The
> Brāhmaṇa saw a beautiful assembly hall filled with groups of Siddhas.
> On seeing this hall of the lord filled with many fragrant scents, he
> was surprised and awestruck. There he saw Śiva, the quiescent
> moon-crested lord with three eyes.
>
> 19. His hand appeared rendered splendid by a trident. He had excellent garment of tiger’s skin. His limbs were smeared with holy ashes and
>     made beautiful. A serpent served the purpose of sacred thread.
> 20. He was delighted in His own self. All his desires had been perfectly realized. He had a lustre equivalent to that of ten million
>     suns. He had five heads and ten arms. His person was ever eager to
>     bless the devotees.
> 21. He was expounding true knowledge and yogic principles to the Siddhas by means of the Tarka-Mudrā (i.e. esoteric gesture by means of
>     fingers to indicate arguments). He was joyously being eulogised by
>     leading Yogins and Pramathas.
> 22. He was encircled by Bhairavas, Yogins as well as Rudras. On seeing Him, Rāma bent down his head (in reverence) with very great joy.
>
> 23-24. **On seeing Kārttikeya to His left, Gaṇeśvara (i.e. Gaṇapati)
> to the right, Nandīśvara, Mahākāla and Vīrabhadra in front of him and
> the hundred-armed Durgā on his (Shiva's) lap, he bowed down to her
> too**. Thereafter, the scholarly sage began to eulogise the lord in
> faltering convulsive speech (overwhelmed with emotions)

**~ Brahmanda Purana Upodghata Pada, Chapter 32**

Maa Rukmini is said to have worshipped Durga before her marriage.

> tasminnudvāhasamaye rukmiṇī rukmabhūṣaṇā | **durgāṃ** niḥsṛtārcayituṃ
> sakhībhirnagarādbahiḥ || 27 ||
>
> At the time of the marriage, Rukmiṇī, having put on golden ornaments,
> went out of the city with her friends to worship Durgā.

**~ Padma Purana, 6.247.27**

Now, let's check Srimad Bhagavatam's retelleing of the same story to see who this 'Durga' was.

> 45. Aged Brāhmaṇa ladies who were well-versed in the (pre-marital) rituals, guided the bride in the **worship and paying respects to the
>     goddess Pārvatī, the Consort of Śiva**, along with god Śiva as well.
> 46. (Rukmiṇī prayed:) I constantly pay my respects to you Oh auspicious[5] Mother goddess, along with your children (Gaṇeśa and
>     Kārttikeya). May Lord Kṛṣṇa become my consort. May this prayer of mine
>     be granted.
> 47. **She worshipped the goddess Pārvatī** in several ways by sprinkling her with water, applying sandal-paste and unbroken
>     rice-grains, varieties of incense, with (a rich variety of) clothes,
>     garlands of flowers, ornaments, various kinds of articles of worship
>     and offerings (variety of edibles) and with rows of lights (waving
>     them round her).

**~ SB 10.53.45-47**

Hence proved beyond doubt Durga is none other than Parvati

Answer (score 2):

Narayana (Vishnu) says to Virabhadra in Brahmanda Purana.:

> *“ekaiva shaktiH parameshvarasya | bhinnA chaturdhA viniyogakAle | bhoge bhavAnI samareShu durgA | kopeShu kALI puruSheshu viShNuH |”*
>
> ***“The ancient Sakti of the Lord (Parameshwara Shiva) appears in four forms; that Sakti becomes Bhavani (Mata Parvati) in her bhoga (grihasth) form, in battle she takes the form of Durga; in anger that of Kali; and she is present in her male form as me (Vishnu/Narayana).”***

Arjuna's Prayer to Maa Durga/Kali before the war, on the suggestions of Lord Krishna.:

MBH 6:23:2.:

> *“[Krishna said to Arjuna]: Cleansing thyself, O mighty-armed one, utter on the eve of the battle thy hymn to **Durga** for (compassing) the defeat of the foe”.*

MBH 6:23:4-5a.:

> *“Arjuna said, – ‘I bow to thee, O leader of Yogins, O thou that art identical with Brahman, O thou that dwellest in the forest of Mandara, O thou that art freed from decrepitude and decay, **O Kali, O wife of Kapala,** O thou that art of a black and tawny hue, I bow to thee. O bringer of benefits to thy devotees, I bow to thee, **O Mahakali, O wife of the universal destroyer,** I bow to thee”.*

In Nava Ratri, 9 forms of Mata Parvati are worshpped which are related to here various life stages and in Durga Puja, we celebrate her as Mata Parvati the Shiv Patni and the mother of Kartik and Ganesha.

Further more, the very 1st verse of Sri Mahishasura Mardini Strotam by Jagat Guru Sri Adi Shankaracharya Maharaj ji starts with.:

> ***"Ayi giri nandini"*** means ***"Oh Daughter of the Mountain."***

And, again ends with.:

> ***"Shaila Suthe"*** which again means ***"The daughter of the Mountain".***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..